# Outlook App on MacOS taking too much space

Tags: macos, email, ms-office, storage

At my workplace we all have Macbook Pro laptops (different models and versions of MacOS)

Went to update one and found it had 110 of its 128gb taken up by System, some digging found that most of this was Microsoft Outlook emails. Had to delete not only the outlook app, but the hidden file within the Library. Seems to be a problem with all the laptops - is there any way of being able to have the Microsoft Outlook app installed without having every single email saved to the harddrive? I know we can use outlook through a web browser, but the consensus is it is preferred through the app.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Outlook comes with help files and a lot of information on Microsoft's web sites. What have you alreay done in terms of research?

Comment: I use Outlook on the web - Chrome does this fine and then only download the attachments I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can typically compress Outlook emails and the pst file: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-the-size-of-your-mailbox-and-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-e4c6a4f1-d39c-47dc-a4fa-abe96dc8c7ef

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clean-up-your-inbox-2fb652e5-b387-4147-9fff-25f2e32dfda9